# My first app displaymessageactivity wont show - Looper.java - no errors

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent, import

I debugged and tried many different things now, but after I click the Send-button, nothing happens, no error, but in debugging mode I trace the program into Looper.java, where it seems to get stuck. Program never reaches the DisplayMessageActivity.

//CUT FROM Looper.java

```java
/**
* Run the message queue in this thread. Be sure to call
* {@link #quit()} to end the loop.
*/
//PROGRAM JUMPS HERE AND...
public static void loop() {
    final Looper me = myLooper();
    if (me == null) {
    throw new RuntimeException("No Looper; Looper.prepare() wasn't called on this thread.");
}
final MessageQueue queue = me.mQueue;

// Make sure the identity of this thread is that of the local process,
// and keep track of what that identity token actually is.
Binder.clearCallingIdentity();
final long ident = Binder.clearCallingIdentity();

for (;;) {
Message msg = queue.next(); // might block
if (msg == null) {
// No message indicates that the message queue is quitting.
return; 
//here my program returns to the top, here: public static void loop() { and comes to   this return-command again, over and over.
}
```

Here is my files: DisplayMessageActivity.java

```java
public class DisplayMessageActivity extends Activity {

@SuppressLint("NewApi")

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

// Create the text view
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
textView.setTextSize(40);

// Show the Up button in the action bar.
//setupActionBar();
// Make sure we're running on Honeycomb or higher to use ActionBar APIs
/*  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
// Show the Up button in the action bar.
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}*/

//Få tak i intenten som kalte på dette objektet
Intent intent = getIntent();
if(intent != null) {
String message=intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
if(message != null) {
textView.setText(message);
}
}
```

MainActivity.java

```java
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
return true;
}

/** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
public void sendMessage(View view) {
// Do something in response to button
System.out.println("sendMessage");
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
String message = editText.getText().toString();
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
//OK TO THIS PLACE...
}
}

// Set the text view as the activity layout
setContentView(textView);
// Show the Up button in the action bar.
}

/**
* Set up the {@link android.app.ActionBar}, if the API is available.
*/
/*@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
private void setupActionBar() {
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
} */
/*
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.display_message, menu);
return true;
}
*/

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
switch (item.getItemId()) {
case android.R.id.home:     
// This ID represents the Home or Up button. In the case of this
NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
return true;
}
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.myfirstapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="8"
android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
<activity
android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity"
android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" 
android:label="@string/app_name" >
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity"
android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >
<meta-data
android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />
</activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

you aren't calling `startActivity(Intent intent)` with your `sendMessage()` intent, so nothing will be done.

Comment: My goodness..&¤"#%! :) I went through this code so many times, guess I didnt the the forest for trees;) THANKS!!

Comment: good to hear you got it working. if the one of the answers helped you its also good practice to accept the answer, then people will be more willing to help you next time :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to startActivity of your intent,
try this code

```
public void sendMessage(View view) {
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
String message = editText.getText().toString();
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
startActivity(intent);}
```